# ManyToOneAssociationField not working in shopware6

Tags: symfony, shopware6

I have category_id column in exclude_categories table.
And in exclude_categories entities, I want to add category entity. So, in Exclude categories definition ExcludeCategoryDefinition, I have

```
protected function defineFields(): FieldCollection
{
    return new FieldCollection([
        (new IdField('id','id'))->addFlags(new Required(), new PrimaryKey()),
        (new FkField('category_id', 'categoryId', CategoryDefinition::class, 'id'))->addFlags(new PrimaryKey(), new ApiAware(), new Required()),
        new ManyToOneAssociationField('category', 'category_id', CategoryDefinition::class, 'id', false ),
    ]);
}
```

But the category shows null.

```
#categoryId: "a515ae260223466f8e37471d279e6406"
  #category: null
  #_uniqueIdentifier: "04bb7ecb26394f5face052f8dc6bf143"
  #versionId: null
  #translated: []
  #createdAt: DateTimeImmutable @1661737483 {#5871 ▶}
  #updatedAt: null
  -_entityName: "customer_specific_prices_exclude_categories"
  -_fieldVisibility: Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\FieldVisibility {#5874 ▶}
  #extensions: array:1 [▶]
  #id: "04bb7ecb26394f5face052f8dc6bf143"
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to add the association to the criteria you are using to fetch the data:

```php
$criteria = new Criteria();
$criteria->addAssociation('category');
```

Alternatively you can also set the association to autoload, if you don't want to add the association manually every time:

```php
new ManyToOneAssociationField('category', 'category_id', CategoryDefinition::class, 'id', true)
```